# how to get percentage symbol from excel in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, percentage

Value in the excel is -45%. How to get percentage (%) symbol while reading excel file using below code.

```
$sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow('A', '3')->getValue()
```

which is giving

```
-0.45
```

But I need the value as

```
-45%
```

Note: Column A will contain all types of values (ex: int, date, string,..)
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

MS Excel stores such a percentage value as `-0.45`, so that it can easily be used in formula calculations; and applies a formatting mask to display it as `45%`.

Assuming that you haven't loaded the file with `setReadDataOnly(true)`, then you simply use

```
$sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow('A', '3')->getFormattedValue();
```